# Passing function from obj into array. Then add up array but result is NaN. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

Here is the code:

```
var myObject = {
  x: 5,
  h: function(){
     varOne = 2*2;
     varTwo = 3*2;
     varThree = varOne*varTwo;
     },
  d: 4
};

var g = myObject.h();
var xyz = g;
var abc = 2;
var efg = 3;
var somearray = [xyz,abc,efg];
var z =  0;
for(i=0; i<somearray.length; i++){
    z += somearray[i];   
}
```

The result is NaN. Why is this? If I do this:
h: function(){return 2*2;}, then I don't have a problem. I'm new to JS and I have spent a lot of time scouring the internet for an answer to no avail. Do I need to use parseInt or parseFloat and, if so, to which variable do I apply it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use more descriptive variable names and it’ll be easier to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not returning any value from the function `h` so it returns undefined which when added results in NaN, try:

```
h: function(){
   var varOne = 2*2;
   var varTwo = 3*2;
   return  varOne*varTwo;
 },
```

Also consider using `var` keyword for the variables defined in a scope otherwise you will end up polluting the global.

Since you are assigning numeric values to the variables, you don't need to parse them using `parseInt`

Comment: YAY! Thank you so much! I feel like an idiot. It works perfectly!

Comment: @HST No worries. If you are satisfied please do remember to mark the answer.

Comment: Will do. I'm just waiting until it lets me do it in 6 more minutes.